# Admin section for website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, admin

I'm wondering if the following thing is possible:

An 'admin' section on a website in which administrators can input a link to an image or video (for example from youtube or google) causing the HTML code on the website to be edited in some way.

For example:

Admin X logs in.
Admin X wants to change a video on their index.html.
Admin X puts the embed code in the input field and presses send.
Website handles the request and updates the website so that everyone may see it.

Does anyone know if this is feasible?

I was thinking that it may be possible using a mix of jQuery, Javascript and PHP, however I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Do you want this in real-time? Anyway.. yeah it's doable

Comment: So far I've tried to make files upload-able with PHP but noticed files greater than 8,26MB can't be uploaded, then my boss came with a suggestion to use VIMEO's embed, and yes real-time is what I was going for, any change made in the admin section should effect the website emmediatly

Comment: You need to change your POST max upload and in php.ini max upload data sizes

Comment: if you want the Client to update the Website if any changes are made, you can search after `Long polling` or `html5 websockets`

Comment: I'll do some research for Long polling and html5 websockets, thank you

Comment: I meant that you can edit those files to change the max upload file size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, creating an admin section will require that you build/use some sort of authentication system and a way to save admin user info and their password hash. You can save the user information with any sort of database, and login using a username/password form page which should be run under https so that login credentials don't get transmitted over the network.

This type of problem you describe is usually solved using a Content Management System (CMS). There are a lot of well known CMS's which are both open source or proprietary, and people will swear by any of them.

It's important for you to try some and figure out which one you feel most comfortable using out of the box, or modifying.

My favorite PHP CMS is [Processwire](http://www.processwire.com) because I find custom fields so easy to implement when using it. You can easily create a field for the site admin to enter the the embed code which will show up when your page renders.

Good Luck!

Comment: My Pleasure :) Hope it helps!

Comment: My apologies, I just noticed I hadn't accepted your answer yet, I've just accepted it, my apologies again.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the whole code into the table's column value.

Fetch that value from the database and just echo it..it will dynamically create it.

```
   echo $row['column_name'];  -- it will be having the html code
```

You can write all the html codes using echo "", for example, in order to create a table you can echo lit like that

```
 echo "<Table><tr><td>DATA IN THE TD </td></tr></table>";
```

That was for embed code, in case of static players just store the video id and load it via database, that will work too.

Comment: they won't be static, they will be custom links as new video's and images will be made and uploaded.

Comment: Great, create a text area in admin panel. Once the user admin logs in, he would be able to view all the videos or their records in the grid. The admin will click on edit button and will see a textarea for the new code to be added (embed one). Just click on saved and on the front end (user side) just echo that value. You are done.